# Неправильное поведение текста при наведении курсора на элемент меню

Tags: html, css, html5

При наведении на элементы меню, текст начинает "прыгать". Шрифт должен меняться с обычного на крупный (bold), а так же внизу должно появляться подчеркивание.

Пробовал использовать следующие вещи, но они не решили мою проблему:

- `solid transparent`
- Увеличивать пространство между элементами

Ниже представлен моего пример кода:

```css
.menu {
  float: right;
}

.menu-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

.menu-link {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-link:hover {
  color: #212121;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
<ul class="menu clearfix ">
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link menu-link-active">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">PRODUCTS</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">HISTORY</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">SHOWROOM</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">CONTACT</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list">
    <a href="#" class=""><img src="img/search.svg" alt="search"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Изменение размера шрифта, в вашем случае, несёт чисто визуально-оформительскую нагрузку (в отличие, например, от тега `<strong>`), поэтому предлагается использовать возможности CSS чуть шире, и `text-shadow` будет оптимальным решением:

```css
.menu { float: right; }

.menu-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

.menu-link {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-link:hover {
  color: #212121;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
  text-shadow: .6px 0px 0px #212121, -.6px 0px 0px #212121;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo"></a>
<ul class="menu clearfix ">
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link menu-link-active">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">PRODUCTS</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">HISTORY</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">SHOWROOM</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list"><a href="#" class="menu-link">CONTACT</a></li>
  <li class="menu-list">
    <a href="#" class=""><img src="img/search.svg" alt="search"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Опередил . Самый толковый вариант, действительно сделать через `text-shadow`, и текст не будет дергаться когда будет наложение толщины якобы и цвет любой можно налаживать и многое другое.

Comment: @And: можно, как вариант, поиграть ещё с `-webkit-text-stroke`, но у него возможностей меньше.

Comment: @UModeL если к примеру установить width и text-align то вообще можно тупо менять font-weight

Comment: @MaximLensky : если задать жёстко ширину или распределить флексом, то да, можно и жирностью шрифта. Как раз в этом и была загвоздка, это и решали.

Comment: @UModeL к примеру 100px хватает всем пунктам ...проверь - я просто свой комментарий удалил там как раз я делал таким образом

Comment: @MaximLensky : ну так никто и не спорит, что можно выделить всем пунктам "фикс", но тогда пробелы между пунктами тоже будут разные.

Comment: @UModeL а ну это так да...чем то надо жертвовать

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu-link {
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 13px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-link:hover {
  padding: 13px 15px;
  color: #212121;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
  text-shadow: .6px 0px 0px #212121, -.6px 0px 0px #212121;
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, для чего Вы привели фрагмент кода из моего ответа?

Comment: @UModeL, новая тактика набрать голоса))))

Comment: @HamSter : так давно уже выяснили, что эта тактика не работает. Но, новичку простительно))

Answer (score -1):

Я немного переделал ваш код.

1. Использовал для меню `flex-box`, чтобы объекты были в ряд.
2. Вместо `<ul>` и `<li>` использовал просто `<a>`, чтобы не прописывать отдельно в CSS строчки по удалению bullet points.
3. Использую `text-stroke`. Не работает в IE( https://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke)

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.nav-logo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}

.nav-logo>img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav-items>a {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-items>a>span {
  padding: 13px 15px;
  color: #8c8c8c;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

.nav-items>a>span:hover {
  color: #212121;
  text-stroke: 1px black;
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #212121;
}

.nav-search>img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="nav-logo">
    <img src="https://pngicon.ru/file/uploads/google.png" alt="logo">
  </a>
  <div class="nav-items">
    <a href=""><span title="Home">Home</span></a>
    <a href=""><span title="Categories">Categories</span></a>
    <a href=""><span title="My">My</span></a>
    <a href=""><span title="Economics">Economics</span></a>
    <a href=""><span title="Eco">Eco</span></a>
    <a href="" class="nav-search">
      <img src="https://www.seonews.ru/upload/iblock/fdd/fdd6bc9a7bfe9b5094c929fed2b447d2.png" alt="Search">
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```